# VBA: Insert a 5000 rows table into SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, vba, sql-update

I am importing an excel table directly to SQL while looping through my table and passing it into a stored procedure in SQL that updates the arguments while looping.

Here is the code:

```
With mobjCmd
    .ActiveConnection = mobjConn
    .CommandText = "MY_INSERT"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandTimeout = 0
End With

While Rn.Offset(nRow).Value <> ""
    With mobjCmd
        .Parameters.Item("@Curr") = Rn.Offset(nRow, 0).Value
        .Parameters.Item("@Client_id") = Rn.Offset(nRow, 1).Value
        .Parameters.Item("@Category") = Rn.Offset(nRow, 2).Value
        .Parameters.Item("@Product_type") = Rn.Offset(nRow, 3).Value
        .Parameters.Item("@Number_items") = Rn.Offset(nRow, 4).Value
        .Parameters.Item("@product_id") = Rn.Offset(nRow, 5).Value
        .Parameters.Item("@Product_name") = Rn.Offset(nRow, 6).Value
        .Parameters.Item("@Quantity") = Rn.Offset(nRow, 7).Value
        .Parameters.Item("@price") = Rn.Offset(nRow, 8).Value

        .Execute
    End With
    
    nRow = nRow + 1
Wend
```

But there is approx 5000 rows so it takes a bit of time every morning. I'd like to find a way to speed up the process and I would take any idea :)

I thought about BULK INSERT but since I need a daily update I don't think this is what I need.

Maybe instead of looping through each row I could create a table (a dictionary or a 2D array) and send the whole thing once... Let me know if you have something interesting to solve this !

Thanks and have a great day

Comment: Inserting, 1 record at a time, when all data is available is  a bit inefficient.
How about creating an SSIS or creating an app to do bulk uploading? Are you familiar with c# or java or any such language?

Comment: thanks for you answer @SrinikaPinnaduwage, I actually did not check but would it work with Python ?

Comment: I think with Python you can do, and just search for VBA Excel bulk insert to SQL

Comment: See whether this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630449/i-need-to-import-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-using-vba

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage thanks for your help, for those in the same situation, you can export data from excel to SQL using a stored procedure but yes it can takes time. One of the ways is using python. For example, you can change the excel into pandas dataframe and send it into SQL !