# How to overcome resource limitation of IN operator in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to pass over 37K values in the WHERE clause using IN operator through Excel VBA macro. However, due to resource limitation in Microsoft SQL Server, the query won't execute. I have tried to pass the values in an array in VBA as well as tried creating a list in in SQL. Neither are able to accommodate these many values. Can somebody help? Sharing the code I have tried below.

```
Dim i as Long
Dim str As String
Dim dict_pn

Set dict_pn = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
i = 1

With InputS
For i = 1 to 50000

str = Trim(.Cells(i, PN_Col).Value)
dict_pn.Add str, 0

Next

With rsPubs
    ' Assign the Connection object.
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs

    .Open Worksheets("SQL Script").Range("A1") & "('" & Join(dict_pn.keys, "','") & "') " & Worksheets("SQL Script").Range("A2") & "('" & Join(dict_pn.keys, "','") & "') " & Worksheets("SQL Script").Range("A3") & "('" & Join(dict_pn.keys, "','") & "') "

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SQL Results").Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs
```

Comment: You put them in a table and then join - you cannot "overcome" the limitation.

Comment: Why in the world would you pass 37K values using an `IN` clause? Not only is that a vast resource hog, it's going to perform like a dog with three broken legs. Put them into a temp table and then do a JOIN on that table instead.

Comment: @KenWhite When I try to create a temp table, even that throws an error saying I cannot insert more than 1000 rows

Comment: @Maxim posted an answer below that will do more than 1000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should transmit data to SQL Server like in [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630449/i-need-to-import-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-using-vba)

```
Sub UpdateTable()

    Dim cnn As Object
    Dim wbkOpen As Workbook
    Dim objfl As Variant
    Dim rngName As Range
    Workbooks.Open "C:\your_path_here\Excel_to_SQL_Server.xls"
    Set wbkOpen = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Set rngName = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown))
    rngName.Name = "TempRange"
    strFileName = wbkOpen.FullName
    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes"";"
    nSQL = "INSERT INTO [odbc;Driver={SQL Server};Server=Server_Name;Database=[Your_Database].[dbo].[TBL]]"
    nJOIN = " SELECT * from [TempRange]"
    cnn.Execute nSQL & nJOIN
    MsgBox "Uploaded Successfully"
    wbkOpen.Close
    Set wbkOpen = Nothing

End Sub
```

and then you can do any you want - use operator IN or LEFT JOIN whith check for null on SQL server side.

You can use temporary table if you will not close connection - temp table exists only in session level.

This is way from VBA code.

Second way - you can use SSIS package to work with excel files. In package you will have same steps - data frlow to transmit data from excel to server and then run sql code to join data. Or you can use join block [inside SSIS package](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1322/merge-multiple-data-sources-with-sql-server-integration-services/).

Third way that you can implement if data in SQL server less than excel row count limit. You can import data from SQL into Excel sheet, and than use VLOOKUP() function to join tables and find related data.